# i need to check whether username is present in db or not.if it is present i shld say already exists..if not i shld insert in db

Tags: java, mysql

I need to check whether username is present in `db` or not. if it is present I should say already exists..if not I should insert in `db`
code follows:

```
ResultSet rs=preparedstatement.executeQuery("select *from re where username='"+unt.getText()+"';");  
    if(rs!=null){
     while(rs.next()){
preparedstatement.executeQuery("select *from re where username="+unt.getText()+";");
             }
     lusn=new JLabel("User Already Exists");  
    }
    else{
    preparedstatement.execute("insert into re values('"+nt.getText()+"','"+unt.getText()+"','"+pas.getText()+"','"+add.getText()+"','"+mail.getText()+"','"+ph.getText()+"');");
    preparedstatement.executeUpdate();
    }
```

kindly help me out
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely unformatted. Format it properly, first of all.

Secondly, you want to check `rs.next()` to see if a row exists, rather than `rs != null'. You don't want to loop rows at all, just figure out whether one exists already, so there shouldn't be any loop in your code -- just a single IF statement.

Lastly, you want to use ? placeholders & assign parameter values -- not be building up parameters into the SQL string, which is very vulnerable to quoting errors & SQL injection security hacks.